# Retrieving data from SQL Server over VPN with PYMSSQL

Tags: sql-server, connection, vpn, pymssql

So, I'm trying to use pymssql to connect to a SQL Server database from my Linux box. The database can only be reached from inside my company's private network. It is set up to accept SQL Server authentication and, from my windows machine, I am able to connect and query it when I am logged on to the VPN (Cisco Anyconnect is the client installed on the Windows box).

The python script works correctly when run on a linux machine that is plugged into the internet at work. I haven't tried it on my windows machine (because, right now, I have no python on that machine, for one).

On my linux machine at home, I have downloaded OpenConnect, which seems to be working fine for establishing a VPN connection. When I run my script from this machine, while on the VPN, I successfully connect to the database. If the test query I use in the script is to creat a table, or manipulate data in the database, it works. However, I am not able to RETRIEVE any data, i.e., if I run a select query, I get [].

(Also, it is perhaps worth mentioning, that the first thing I tried to do, before figuring out how to get a VPN client on my linux machine (at first I was messing around with Cisco stuff which was a nightmare), was to ssh from my windows machine inside the private network to my home linux machine while forwarding a port from my home linux machine to 1433 on the SQL Server machine. Then instead of using pymsswl.connect() to connect to the SQL SERVER machine, I connected to my local port. I observed the same behavior, actually, in this case as over the VPN. I wasn't particularly surprised that I couldn't get data back in that case, since it's overwrought, and I could see SQL Server not knowing where to send the data....although I am really just speculating there anyway...)

I should also mention that when I click around in the Cisco folder on my Windows machine, there is a "security catalog" with all kinds of wonkiness in it that I don't know much about. Maybe these certificates/thumbprints are at play.

So, I admit total noobness here, and would appreciate any help. If I said something senseless, or if there is other information that might apply, I'll do my best to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

Are you logging in with SQL Server authentication? And how are you running your queries? Sproc have implied rights, meaning if your using a table that you don't have access to it will still work but doing a simple select will deny access, Long shot but who knows.

Here is a link where Pinal Dave talks about a similar error and goes through in detail how to check to make sure the instance is up and a number of other troubleshooting steps you should try. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/05/21/sql-server-fix-error-provider-named-pipes-provider-error-40-could-not-open-a-connection-to-sql-server-microsoft-sql-server-error/